# making an Image-button start, stop and restart

Tags: java, android

Literally started coding for the first time just about 2 weeks ago, so I apologize if my description of the problem might be confusing, but I will try.

I've created an imageButton and when press it I want this to happen:

- First Click = Start playing a random audio.
- Second Click = Stop the current audio playing.

I want this to go in a infinite loop.

Start random audio -> Stop audio - > Start random audio...

But with my code (see image) https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kO9i.png

what it does right now is:

- First Click = Start playing random audio.
- Second Click = Stop playing audio and restarts the whole class.

I've tried numerous ways to change the Intent or using a switch instead. But I can't get it to go into a loop.

Comment: It's better to post your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this :

```
// Delcare a boolean as an attribute to be accessible inside the listener
private boolean isPlaying = false;

// Inside onCreate(), set a listener on your Button myButton
Mediaplayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yourfile);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if (!isPlaying) {
         // Not playing music
         // START RANDOM MUSIC with mp.start()
         mp.start()
         isPlaying = true;
      }
      else {
         // Playing music
         // STOP CURRENT PLAYED MUSIC with mp.stop()
         mp.stop()
         isPlaying = false;
      }      
    }
  });
```

**EDIT** : MediaPlayer class has a method for this !

```
// Inside onCreate(), set a listener on your Button myButton
Mediaplayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yourfile);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
         // Not playing music
         // START RANDOM MUSIC with mp.start()
         mp.start()
      }
      else {
         // Playing music
         // STOP CURRENT PLAYED MUSIC with mp.stop()
         mp.stop()
      }      
    }
  });
```

Best

Comment: It's saying "Cannot assign a value to final variable isPlaying".

When I press on the red light bulb "to transform into final one elemental array" it changes some code. when i press run app and click imagebutton, it just start playing and nothing else happens after clicking the imgebutton a second time.

Comment: Did you set this variable as an attribute of your class with the keyword `final` ?

Comment: That's not possible. This error means that `isPlaying` has been declared `final`. In other word, you can only assign a value during declaration. It's not possible to change this value after that. May be you have another `isPlaying` variable elsewhere ?

Comment: And you don't need to declare `isPlaying` as an array. Just use my code. Moreover, you are assigning a new `OnClickListener` inside the `onClick()` method, that's not correct. Use the example I provided to you and replace my comments with the code you wrote to play the music.

Comment: Stop sharing images... Just copy/paste your code in your first post. I won't help you if I have to write your code on my own.

Comment: And you should really attend an Android tutorial class. I think you miss some crucial things in Android programming. Here is a good tutorial for beginners : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/

Comment: And I made a mistake, the `isPlaying` should be declared as an attribute of your class. Indeed, you cannot access this variable if it is declared inside `onCreate()`. That's why Android Studio tells you to make it `final`. Post your code in text and I'll send you a working example with comments.

Comment: Got everything to work! Really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the subject answered :) I'll modifiy my answer as well.